The popular post div in the sidebar does not scroll down when scroll
negarip.com That is my website.
I added the codes for the div part I want to work, but it does not work because the sidebar ends there. I want the popular posts section in the sidebar to stay on the right of the screen until I get to the end of the page. how do I do it.
When I add the css code to the top dive, it works as I want, but it still doesn't work as I want because there is no other div under the last div part.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
